# How do I prefix a text to an Excel column? - all numbers are in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

For example, if the number is 123456, I want it to become RNE123456.

Comment: Do you want it to only display as `RNE123456` or become the text `RNE123456`? Becoming text will mean you will not be able to carry out mathematical operations on it, while changing only the display allows you to carry out mathematical operations on it.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you need?

- Select required cells (whichever cells you want automatically prefixed) and right click for the context menu, then select Format Cells (or press  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd>)
- Select Custom from Category list.
- Type in:

  ```
  "RNE"General
  ```

If you want to change the prefix obviously you can remove RNE and input any prefix string.

Press *OK* and return to the spreadsheet. It should automatically prefix the rows.

*Image of Format Cells dialog*
[image]

*Enlarging column should fix 'E' errors:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did the same , but the general numbers r showing as "RNE1.2012E+11
" . how do I change to numbers with the text RNE120.....245

Comment: @Dalmon All you need to do is enlarge the column or row and it will rectify instantly. Thanks!

Comment: No dear i have tried the same before mailing & even now , remain same . RNE1.2012E+11 , another problem I noticed is the same no is getting copied in entire coloum .

Comment: @Dalmon I think it works in rows but if you want the actual column to be prefixed i think you might need another solution. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom format `_ "RNE" @_`.

This works also on numbers.
You can also type this format under conditional formatting to apply to more creative answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use just the Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) feature?

[image]